# Make a temporary rule that all transaction on a table happen to the same table on a different server

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a rule that if I were to fetch data from lets say table sales_region_t on server 1 then  the data will be fetched from sales_region_t in server 2.
Basically I have a application that I need to test against a clients DB that is on the other side of the world and it take forever when connecting to their DB. I have just about all the correct data on my local DB to the exception of sales_region_t. So, there is one table namely sales_region_t that I need to test with the data that is found on their DB. 
What I would like to do is, to run the app against my local DB and set some type of trigger that when data is fetched from sales_region_t that it points to sales_region_t that is found on the clients DB.

Comment: Can you not just get a backup of the client db and restore it locally?

Comment: To pull the clients DB across the network will take a few hours. Not really a viable option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a synonym would do you well here. Here's the steps (all in your local db):

1. `exec sp_rename 'dbo.sales_region_t', 'save_sales_region_t', 'object'`
2. `create synonym [dbo].[sales_region_t] for [server2].[database2].[dbo].[sales_region_t]`

Comment: Can\How do I drop the synonym once I am done testing?

Comment: `Drop synonym` and rename the table back.